# Spring JPA - Define SQL function for usage in custom query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's assume we've an Spring JPA based repository

```
@Repository
public interface MyClassRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, Long> {

}
```

with the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classes")
public class MyClass {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    // Getter + Setter
}
```

I tried to find all stored records within a given instance around a referenced object. For calculating the distance between first object's position and second object's position I thought about a custom `@Query` in combination with the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM MyClass c WHERE :distance >= haversine(c, :origin)")
public List<Passenger> findAll(@Param("origin") MyClass origin, @Param("distance") double distance);
```

Is it possible to define the SQL function `haversine()` in an additional query, e.g. `@Query("CREATE FUNCTION haversine(...) ...")`, because I've to use this function in multiple custom queries and I try to prevent code repetition. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your Sql function through for example db migrations, as usual, and extend org.hibernate.dialect (see how it made for Postgis for example) and don't forget specify the dialect for your data source

```
 public class YourDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {
          public YourDialect() {
            super();
            registerFunction("haversine", new StandardSQLFunction("haversine", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE));
      }
}
```

Comment: Same as above, using this solution I must define the function database related let's say for mysql. But I want to be db implememtation independent

Answer (score 0):

You must create a function in your DB. Functions are "static" elements - they must be present in DB on the time of the query execution.

Also, you have some errors in your method.
In the query you select from the table "MyClass", but your method returns "List".

Comment: Sure but my actual calculation logic is database independent. I want to be able to exchange my underlying database... I thought about something like a hibernate preprocessor inserting my actual logic